# Graphql scalar type for a value that can be string or object?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

i have an api for sign up which returns error of string or null,

```
error: 'Email already use' or error: null
```

how do i construct it in schema? what i have now is this:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Mutation {
    signUp(email: String, password: String): String
  }
`;
```

since typeof null is object, how can i make it like this in graphql?

```
signUp(email: String, password: String): String || Object
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL has a [standard syntax for returning error values](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#response) and your schema does not directly need to account for this.

In your schema I would “unconditionally” return whatever type you’d normally expect to return:

```
type UserAccount { ... }
type Query {
  me: UserAccount # or null if not signed in
}
type Mutation {
  signUp(email: String!, password: String!): UserAccount!
}
```

If it’s unsuccessful, you will get back a null field value (even though the schema in theory claims it shouldn’t) and an error.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "It didn’t work",
      "locations": [ { "line": 2, "column": 3 } ],
      "path": [ "signUp" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL you can define what field can be `null` and what can't. 
Take a look at the docs: 
https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields

> **String** is one of the built-in scalar types - these are types that
>   resolve to a single scalar object, and can't have sub-selections in
>   the query. We'll go over scalar types more later.
>
> **String!** means that the field is non-nullable, meaning that the GraphQL service promises
>   to always give you a value when you query this field. In the type
>   language, we'll represent those with an exclamation mark.

So in case of your schema String is absolutely fine. It can be null

```
type Mutation {
  signUp(email: String, password: String): String
}
```